# How to redirect user to home page if authenticated

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, authentication, ionic-framework

I have an Angular 14 + Ionic 6 app where I would like to redirect an already logged in user directly to home screen of the app instead of showing him login page every time he reopens the app...

Here is the code I wrote but it does not seem to work...

**app-routning.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'login',
    loadChildren: () => import('./login/login.module').then( m => m.LoginPageModule),
    canLoad: [AutoLoginGuard]
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'login',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    loadChildren: () => import('./home/home.module').then( m => m.HomePageModule),
    canLoad: [AuthGuard]
  },
]
```

**auth.guard.ts**

```
export class AuthGuard implements CanLoad {
  constructor(
    private authService: AuthenticationService,
    private router: Router
  ) {}

  canLoad(
    route: Route,
    segments: UrlSegment[]): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
    return this.authService.isAuthenticated.pipe(
      filter((val) => val !== null),
      take(1),
      map((isAuthenticated) => {
        if (!isAuthenticated) {
          this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
          return false;
        } else {
          if (route.path === '/login') {
            this.router.navigateByUrl('/home');
            console.log('Already loged in');
          } else {
            return true;
          }
        }
      })
    );
  }
}
```

And here is my authentiacation service:
**authentication.service.ts**

```
export class AuthenticationService {
  isAuthenticated: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(null);
  token = '';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.loadToken();
  }

  async loadToken() {
    const token = await Preferences.get({ key: 'TOKEN_KEY' });
    if (token && token.value) {
      console.log('set token: ', token.value);
      this.token = token.value;
      this.isAuthenticated.next(true);
    } else {
      this.isAuthenticated.next(false);
    }
  }

  login(credentials: { email; password }): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(`${environment.apiUrl}auth/login`, credentials).pipe(
      map((data: any) => data.authorization.token),
      switchMap((token) => from(Preferences.set({ key: 'TOKEN_KEY', value: token }))),
      tap(_ => {
        this.isAuthenticated.next(true);
      })
    );
  }

  logout(): Promise<void> {
    this.isAuthenticated.next(false);
    return Preferences.remove({ key: 'TOKEN_KEY' });
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just return the authentication state in your Guard like this:

```
   canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree
  {
    return this.authService.isAuthenticated.value;
  }
```

add to your component ts

```
constructor()
{
    this.auth.isAuthenticated.subscribe(res =>
    {
      if (this.authService.isAuthenticated.value === false)
      {
        this.authService.Logout();
      }
      if (this.authService.isAuthenticated.value === true)
      {
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
      }
    }
}
```

Now you can Logout/ Give access to the site by just changing isAuthenticated

Also if you don't want the user to need to login every time you should probably implement Refresh Tokens.